# how to get rid of extra space in the header image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
html, body {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}

.nav {
  margin:0px;
}

.navbar{
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.header{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--font family-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body >
    <!--Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="conatiner-fluid">
        <!--page scroll button for -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target= "#myNavbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-scroll">Website</a>
        </div> <!--page scroll button-->
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav  navbar-nav navbar-right" id="#myNavbar">
              <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
              <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#about">About</a></li> 
              <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> <!--ul-li-->
        </div> <!--navbar collapse--> 
      </div> <!--container-fluid--> 
    </nav>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <!--Header-->
    <header > 
      <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
          <img src="work.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--Header-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm coding my first website there's some unwanted white space around the header image that won't go away.

I've checked all the usual solutions like setting margin and `padding:0;display: block` and `width:100%` but they  don't seem to be working.

Could somebody please take a look at the code  and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the

```
<div class="container"> to <div class="container-fluid">
```

and give your image

```
width= 100%.
```

Something like:

```
<style>
  .width_full {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="work.jpg" class="img-responsive width_full">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]